# Maxent out of bound error?

Tags: qgis, file-formats, ascii, esri-ascii-raster, maxent

I selected my climate data from wordclim ( tile 29 ) and then used QGis to convert the data
to .asc format . My occurrence data is in degree decimal.But when I run Maxent on any layer
it says that the occurrence points are out of environment bound.
What should I do ??

Comment: For those who get stuck on same problem , make sure occurrence data is in degree decimal and environmental layers in WSG84 format.Also the number of rows , columns and cell size of each ascii file should be same :).

Comment: Just to add to user77146 's answer... also try using a snap raster (the first one you process) to snap all the other rasters to.